# How to check file lock on .txt file before opening

Tags: excel, vba, file, text, locking

Long story short... I am using a pc to open a .txt file located on a server... but sometimes the .txt file is not finished (there is still data stored in a buffer of the source computer).

```
FilePath = "D:\test.txt"

Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
```

Someone smarter than I am has identified that the .txt file is "locked" by the operating system until it is finished but I am still able to open it. I would like to wait for the .txt file to be "not locked" before opening it. How do I do this?

Note: The "smarter" person than me explained... the .txt file can be opened by a "dumb" program like "notepad" but if you try to use "Microsoft Word" to open it... you get a message telling you that it is locked...

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

is_open = False

while not(is_open):
    try:
        f = open('test.txt','w')
        is_open=True
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well the code below will work for your scenario.

- You could change the constants into parameters (if you think their values need to change/be determined dynamically).
- You could also change the `GetFileOrWait`'s implementation such that it allows an infinite loop (I chose to avoid this, but maybe you want this).
- All in all, the below is basically a function which tries to return the workbook in 120 seconds (or times out with an error) -- which you can hopefully use in a parent subroutine/procedure.
- You may be able to specify finer frequencies (seconds may be too coarse) by using `Timer` instead or other lower level APIs.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Function GetFileOrNothing() As Workbook
    Const FILE_PATH As String = "D:\test.txt" ' Could pass this in as argument (if needed).
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetFileOrNothing = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FILE_PATH, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Function GetFileOrWait() As Workbook
    ' Attempts to open a file. If access fails, waits n seconds before trying again.
    ' This function raises an error (times out to prevent infinite loop) after N seconds.
    Const MAXIMUM_WAIT_IN_SECONDS As Long = 10
    Const INTERVAL_WAIT_IN_SECONDS As Long = 1

    Dim timeToStopAt As Date
    timeToStopAt = DateAdd("s", MAXIMUM_WAIT_IN_SECONDS, Now)

    Do While Now < timeToStopAt
        Dim outputWorkbook As Workbook
        Set outputWorkbook = GetFileOrNothing()

        If Not (outputWorkbook Is Nothing) Then Exit Do
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", INTERVAL_WAIT_IN_SECONDS, Now)
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If outputWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 5, , "Failed to access file within the specified time frame."
    End If

    Set GetFileOrWait = outputWorkbook
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because I can open the file just fine whether someone already has it open or not. The way it was explained to me was that the txt file is too "dumb" to know whether the file is already open and notepad is too "dumb" to know that the file is already open. However, the operating system (windows in my case) places a file lock on the txt file. So, if i try to open it using a "smarter" program (MS Word for example) then it will see that it is already open. At any rate... I still never found a solution to this issue. The best i think i could do is try to use word to open

Comment: But i feel there is probably a better way.